# Perforce - Changes not saved in workspace-client view

Tags: perforce-client-spec

When I executed "p4 client" to make some changes in my workspace view on MacOS High Sierra for perforce, the changes were not saved and command "p4 client" at the prompt did not close (exit) when I closed the workspace-view file.

Can someone please tell me what I am missing/doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue by deleting the existing workspace view and created a new workspace view. In the new workspace view, I simply mapped the depot to /my_workspace_view/. Before, I mapped the depot to /my_workspace_view///...

Comment: You should approve your own answer, because you get important credit from the system here for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

In my configuration, `p4 client <workspace_name>` opened TextMate (a GUI app), and simply saving and closing the document left the terminal waiting for changes.

The trick was to save and *quit* TextMate, and the client was saved correctly.

Comment: That actually helped me , had to close sublime and to get the changes written. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the `p4 client` command was opening the tmp file in Sublime Text. When trying to save edits to the client workspace specification, ST would show the "Save As" window in the `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp` directory. Saving the file there wasn't making the changes to the client spec.

To solve this, I edited the `p4config.cfg` file in my workspace root. Since `P4EDITOR` wasn't specified, I added the following line.

```
P4EDITOR="C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"
```

After doing this, `p4 client` opens the client spec in notepad, and saving the file and closing it commits the changes to the spec as expected.